# Securing RESTful Web API where Identity Provider and Authorization Host are the same server

Tags: security, rest, ssl, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

I am tasked with securing a RESTful Web API against myriad attacks (phishing, replay, collisions etc.).

We have decided that the technologies best suited for this purpose include:

- TLS (between API and application to prevent phishing)
- OAuth 2 (to provide authorization to different user applications)
- Claims-based auth (various user access rules)
- ASP.NET Web API 2

The issue we're presented with is that the Identity Provider is an existing in-house library which would reside on the same server as the authorization provider (which will speak to a custom STS). We have two clients as well: a web application and a native tablet application, both of which must securely interact with the API (hence the tokenization).

My question: is the approach outlined above viable or necessary? And is OAuth (password-credential grant) overkill for this scenario?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?